# Logstash: Copy array field into another

Tags: arrays, logging, copy, field, logstash

I would like to know if there is any simple way in logstash to copy all the elements of one field array to another. Put another way, is there a way to copy all the nested fields of a top-level field to another top-level field?

I'm having this problem because I'm dealing with a nonstandard multiline log format which is not necessarily thread-safe. So in order to make sure I get all the data I need and in the right order, I'm currently on planning on throwing every relevant value of each type into an array, and then sorting them out later. The problem I'm having is that logstash doesn't seem to support too much array manipulation. If you think my approach just won't work at all in logstash, any suggestions as to what I could do instead would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question almost shows: [LogStash: How to make a copy of the @timestamp field while maintaining the same time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189872/logstash-how-to-make-a-copy-of-the-timestamp-field-while-maintaining-the-same) you can use the ruby filter to copy an array.

```
filter {
  ruby {
        code => "event['another_top_level_field'] = event['top_level_field']"
  }
}
```