# LogStash: How to make a copy of the @timestamp field while maintaining the same time format?

Tags: logstash

I would like to create a copy of the `@timestamp` field such that it uses the same format as `@timestamp`.

I've tried the following:

```
mutate
{
    add_field => ["read_time", "%{@timestamp}"]
}
```

but while `@timestamp` is in the format: `2014-08-01T18:34:46.824Z`,

the `read_time` is in this format `2014-08-01 18:34:46.824 UTC`

This is an issue as Kibana doesn't understand the "UTC" format for histograms.

Is there a way using the date filter to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kibana can't understand because the `read_time` field is a string, not a timestamp!
You can use `ruby` filter to do what you need. Just copy the @timestamp to a new field `read_time` and the field time is in **timestamp**, not string. The `add_field` is add a new field with **string type**!

Here is my config:

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter {
    ruby {
            code => "event['read_time'] = event['@timestamp']"
    }
    mutate
    {
        add_field => ["read_time_string", "%{@timestamp}"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

You can try and see the output, the output is:

```
{
   "message" => "3243242",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-08-08T01:09:49.647Z",
      "host" => "BENLIM",
 "read_time" => "2014-08-08T01:09:49.647Z",
"read_time_string" => "2014-08-08 01:09:49 UTC"
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: You saved my day. I tried using `date` filter with `match` by `@timestamp` and `target` to a new field, but for some reason `date` failed to parse its own timestamp - throwing a `cannot parse` exception. This solution solved the problem.

Comment: Direct subscripting has been removed since Logstash 5. You'll need to use the `set`/`get` methods instead: `event.set('read_time', event.get('@timestamp'))`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to run any Ruby code. You can just use the [`add_field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field) setting of the [Mutate filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html):

```
mutate {
    # Preserve "@timestamp" as "logstash_intake_timestamp"
     add_field => { "logstash_intake_timestamp"=> "%{@timestamp}" }
}
date {
    # Redefines "@timestamp" field from parsed timestamp, rather than its default value (time of ingestion by Logstash)
    # FIXME: include timezone:
    match => [ "timestamp_in_weird_custom_format", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
    tag_on_failure => ["timestamp_parse_failed"]
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```