# add date ingested to Logstash event

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash is correctly parsing the event time (@timestamp) of my events. However, I'd like to *also* have the date the event is ingested by ELK.

I know that [`date`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) works well to extract the timestamp. However, I don't know how to say "put the current time in arbitrary_field".

I'm doing the following, but there's gotta be a better way.

```
 ruby {
   code => "event['ingest_time'] = Time.now.utc.strftime '%FT%TZ'"
 }
```

Comment: There is no stock "put the current time in arbitrary_field" filter, so your ruby filter is about as good as it gets.

Comment: I keep meaning to test it, but have you tried mutate->add_field, using the original @timestamp value?

Comment: @AlainCollins I like the idea. I tried that, with `add_field => { "fieldname" => "@timestamp" }` and it put, literally, `@timestamp` in my new field. That led me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189872/logstash-how-to-make-a-copy-of-the-timestamp-field-while-maintaining-the-same), but that comes back to "do the ruby thing".

Comment: any opinions on if this is actually answerable, based on the above link?

Comment: Well, now I know that mutate doesn't work as I hoped!  I like that link's use of @timestamp as the source rather than your use of strftime, though.

Answer (score 3):

For logstash 5.x or above, you need to use this:

```
  ruby {
   code => "event.set('logstash_time' , Time.now.utc.strftime('%FT%TZ'))"
  }
```

If you have no timestamp in your data, you can use the line below, as logstash add one if missing

```
add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
```

But if you do have one already, this method can't be used. Notice that if you later set a timestamp with `date {}`, this may work if done before that...

I didn't see any performance problem in using the first and it works all the time, so that one is the recommended one

Answer (score 2):

The following creates an ISO8601 format date that is recognized properly by Elasticsearch.

```
filter {
 ruby {
    code => "event.set('ingested_time' , Time.now.utc)"
 }
}
```

_source:

```
"ingested_time" : "2019-01-24T17:40:07.990Z",
```

mapping:

```
 "ingested_time" : {
      "type" : "date"
  },
```

Answer (score -4):

```
add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the submission date instead of the reception one?

Comment: I think that depends on the input.  For example, I've been using the GELF input, and it uses the value of the timestamp field in the incoming packet as @timestamp.  Unfortunately, that still doesn't make this answer right.